# About Application launcher basket bug

Tags: launcher

After installing the brand new Ubuntu 20.4 LTS on my old laptop to give it a new life, this problem occurred when I created a basket/ folder in the Ubuntu application launcher, when we drag a application over to each other, they create a folder..... We can name the folder too, that wasn't the issue here, the problem was when I dragged the applications over each other after creating a new folder and naming it, I exited the folder after my job of creating it was done, my system simply hanged displaying the frequents tab and  all applications tab with no applications in it. This had happen to me a lot of times after I view a folder of applications and click somewhere around it to exit it, It simply hangs showing those two tabs. No one has ever experienced this but this bug only occurred on my system. Does anyone know how to fix this bug? Thanks in advance.